# Detect unlock screen type on Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to detect how actually user unlock phone? - via PIN or pattern or using swipe gesture I've googled only smth about registering `Receiver` with this code in `onReceive()`

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = 
            (KeyguardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure())
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit the context of this ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan I'm writing a payment application and I need to know how user unlocked his phone (graphical pattern, number pin, swipe gesture) before making payment because there's different payment implementations (it's about security)

Comment: So you need to know exactly the `TYPE`, not just if he did or not completed the patern.

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan exactly))

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan and I don't know if it's possible to retrieve TYPE

Comment: Yes, as you got in the answer..seems like that was is the closest one to what you will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Settings.Secure.getLong method is deprecated since API level 23, and that it has been replaced by the **KeyGuardManager**, it doesn't seem possible to retrieve the exact lock type.

As you've found out, using **isDeviceSecure()** is the closest information you can retrieve.